# Display date in datagrid without repeating its values C#,sql

Tags: c#, sql

[image: totalexpense]

How can I display the dates without repeating and without time. For example:

The column date should display

```
8/29/2016 
9/2/2016
```

I have a picture of my UI below. Thanksss. :)

Comment: Where are you getting the data?  I imagine you could select just the values you want (the date component, not the time component) and filter for distinct values, no?

Comment: Column data type? Which dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply in the sql query, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Or in C#, do the following:

```
//Create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
 String.Format( "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" , dt);
```

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");  
 dt.ToShortDateString();